# How to get selected fields from an array using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, testcomplete

Please bear with me, I am new to coding. I am trying to test a web service and I am stuck with a java script array where I need to get 2 fields out of 10 fields for further testing. I would really appreciate if someone can help me with it?

Comment: You can access those fields directly with `a['fieldname']`.

Comment: hey, could you give a little more info about what you are trying to do? Which fields do you want to get? Any two? Two specific ones?

Comment: Get all the Latitude and Longitude values and verify if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
<script>
        let colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];
        alert(colors[2]);
</script>
```

or more generic:

```
<script>
    let colors = ["Red", "Green", "Blue"];

    //Output: Blue (Note that arrays starts with 0)
    PrintArrayValue(colors, 2);

    function PrintArrayValue(array, index){
        alert(array[index]);
    }
</script>
```